# Is this definition consistent and correct (infinite set)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

A set $S$ is infinite iff $\forall x\in S \exists x_0\in S$ s.t. $x \leq x_0$. Obviously, by that definition we can say, since $x_0\in S \implies\exists {x_0}_{0}\in S$ s.t. $x_0\leq {x_0}_0$. Ad infinitum.

This is obviously for well-ordered sets. I can't seem to find anything wrong with this definition. Any help appreciated!

Comment: @DonThousand darn it, didn't think about that. Please write that as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @DonThousand, I am aware of the canonical definitions, regards

Comment: there is something along the lines of what you say, but replace $\le$ with $<$. Also, you need to specify what you mean by $\le$ (or by $<$). (Is it a (strict) linear order, could you have cycles like $x_0<x_1<x_0$?)

Comment: @Mirko, great Idea. That might work! regards

Comment: the axiom of infinity in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory has a similar statement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity There is a non-empty set $S$ (containing the empty set as an element, $\emptyset\in S$) such that if $x\in S$ then also $x\cup\{x\}\in S$. Note in particular that $x\in x\cup\{x\}$, so we get "bigger and bigger" elements of $S$, intuitively $S$ is infinite. The axiom or regularity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity also plays a role, to avoid the possibility of cycles like $x\in x$ or $x_1\in x_2\in\cdots\in x_n\in x_1$. The set $\Bbb N$ is defined later.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost Note (and I commented this below DonThousand's answer) that the canonical definitions mentioned here *aren't* accurate in $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, $x\leq x$, so this is true for any non-empty set with an ordering. There are two canonical definitions of infinite sets

1. $S$ is infinite if there exists an injection $f:\mathbb N\to S$.
2. $S$ is infinite if for some $s\in S$, there exists an injection $f:S\to S\setminus\{s\}$.

Comment: Actually, neither of these defines infinite sets in the absence of choice - rather, they're equivalent definitions of *Dedekind-infiniteness*. Of course that's usually not relevant, but it's worth observing. (One fully-accurate definition of "infinite" is "not in bijection with any Dedekind-finite well-orderable set." Actually "not in bijection with any finite ordinal" is better, but can feel a bit slippery at first.)

Comment: Yea, I'm aware that ZF is consistent with the existence of Dedekind-finite infinite sets, but frankly, I work in choice environments for most of what I do, so it is basically second nature at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set $\{1,2,3\}$ which is finite,but check that your definition still holds fo it.There are two equivalent definitions:

$1$.A set$S$ is said to be infinite iff it is not a finite set i.e. there does not exist any bijection $\phi:S\to\{1,2,...,n\}$ for any $n\in \mathbb N$.

$2$.A set $S$ is said to be infinite iff there exists a proper subset of $S$ equivalent to $S$.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I know those definitions. I was asking if the definition given in my original question is erroneous or not. Regards

Comment: Alright.........

Comment: Okay............